How do I connect the three sets of wires in this switch box
Three wires coming into the switch box. One set for the outlets in the room.  Another for the light. The third is the power coming from the main panel.  How do I wire these.

Please try to provide a lot more info on what you are attempting. We cannot see "this switch box".

" How do I wire these." ?    Carefully.

it depends on the functionality that you want

Can you post photos of the inside of the switch box please?

I'm going to take a guess that you want continuous power to the outlet and you have a load (like a light) that you want the switch to operate.  That would be wired like this:
I am not an electrician, and word of warning...if the switch is doesn't have a load and is returning hot on the neutral wire (I.E. you're trying to use the switch to switch on and off the outlet...this will cause a short and this will not work).
As others have said, we need more detail on what you're trying to do to be 100% sure.  Also I'm not sure on code, but you might need a small wire on the hot to bind the hot for the outlet to line and then line to switch...I'll defer code compliance (i.e. is box big enough) and other considerations to others.

